# Line numbering doesn't work

Tags: line-numbering

I need a help, I wrote some algorithmic pseudocode in Latex and I want to show all the line numbers, no like on the image, every second.

Thank you for help.

[image: How that look]

Latex Code

```
\documentclass[a1paper,0pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\begin{document}
\SetWatermarkAngle{109}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{BubbleSort()} 
    \begin{algorithmic}[2]
        \For {$i = 0 \textbf{ to } velkostPola-2$}
            \For {$j = 0 \textbf{ to } velkostPola-2$}
                \If {$pole[j] > pole[j+1]$} 
                \State $vymena(pole[j],pole[j+1])$
                \EndIf
            \EndFor
        \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{InsertionSort()} 
    \begin{algorithmic}[2]
        \For {$i = 0 \textbf{ to } velkostPola-2$}
            \State $atributP \gets pole[i]$
            \State $atributJ \gets i-1$
            \While {$(atributJ >= 0)\textbf{ AND }(atributP < pole[atributJ])$}
                \State $pole[atributJ+1] \gets pole[atributJ]$
                \State $atributJ \gets atributJ-1$
            \EndWhile
            \State $pole[atributJ+1] \gets atributP$
        \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Thanks for a fairly concise example. One minor thing though: it includes a command `\SetWatermarkAngle` which is not defined by any of the packages that are included, so in it's current form you get an error if you try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is determined by the optional argument to the `algorithmic` environment. So when you do

```
\begin{algorithmic}[2]
```

that means every second line is numbered. To number all lines, use

```
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
```